# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '(localidad=localidad,Pnombre=nombre,precio=precio,tamaño=tamaño) WHERE idPr...' en la linea 3

Tags: sql

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE editar(IN localidad VARCHAR(30), IN nombre VARCHAR (20),IN precio DECIMAL, IN tamaño VARCHAR(20),IN idProd INT(2))
BEGIN
    UPDATE productos SET (localidad=localidad,Pnombre=nombre,precio=precio,tamaño=tamaño) WHERE idProductos=idProd;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

// Ahora bien mi duda es porque me sale ese error, la tabla de productos tiene datos.
Ahora bien, pienso que el problema esta en los parametros, y la duda es el porque, ya que soy nueva con procedimientos y lo necesito para tareas y poder implementarlas con PHP :C , espero que puedan ayudarme

Comment: No metas entre paréntesis las columnas y valores a actualizar

Comment: Haz lo que te recomienda @BetaM pero además intenta evitar usar Ñ en los nombres de las columnas/variables, así como tampoco se deben usar tildes ni carácteres "extraños".

Comment: Voy a hacer eso, se los saque y me lo tomo, ahora voy a probar con el que tengo que hacer la actividad, que sale un error parecido, cualquier cosa lo subo acá, muchas gracias